# vlookup with if Function

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, export-to-excel

I'm trying to combine VLOOKUP and IF function. you can see in below picture where I'm try to put formula if left side address matched with right side address, (IF B2 Address = to F2 Address then Output show G cell text "HOME", "DISTRIBUTOR" in location cell D2) otherwise if address not matched with any addresses then show "WORK".
is it any other formula for this

[image]]

Comment: Cell D2 might be =IF(B2=F2,"HOME","WORK")  but what is the criteria for "HOME" or "DISTRIBUTION" if cells B2 and F2 are the same?

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya IF B2 Address = F2 Address then show G2 otherwise show "WORK"

Comment: @DrCorgi IF B2 Address = F2 Address then show G2 otherwise show "WORK"

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya yes, it will be in same row

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya can you please write in for me

Comment: @DrCorgi has already wrote it for you, please refer

Comment: Are the addresses on the right randomly arranged? And you want each cell on the left "looked up" in the right addresses coulmn, and if it is there, then output "Home or Distribution" else "WORK?"

Comment: @AliMustafa yes you understand my problem, just if cell on the left "looked up" in the right addresses column, and if it is there, then output G2 cell data otherwise show "WORK"

Comment: You have limited addresses in the F column, and for that, this formula should work, `=IF(IFNA(VLOOKUP(B2, F2:F26, 1, FALSE ) = B2, FALSE), "HOME, DISTRIBUTOR", "WORK")`.

Comment: @AliMustafa ok i understand but what i want is G2 Text in D2, if B2=F2, otherwise show "WORK". please read my question again thank you for your affect.

Comment: `=IF(IFNA(VLOOKUP(B2, F2:F26, 1, FALSE ) = B2, FALSE), VLOOKUP(B2, F2:G26, 2, FALSE ), "WORK")` this will do.

Answer (score 0):

Are your preferred using index and match function?

--edit--

Input this formula in cell D2 and drag down, its should work fine, I'd tried in my system and work.

=IFERROR(IF(MATCH($B2,$F$2:$F$26,FALSE)>0,INDEX($G$2:$G$26,MATCH($B2,$F$2:$F$26,FALSE))),"Work")

Note:
$F$2:$F$26 & $G$2:$G$26 => is your reference data, the INDEX & MATCH function will be search the match item from this reference data.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).